# Добавть перменную из php в html

Tags: php

Мне надо вывести эту переменную

```
`$a=  ' <div class="span9" id="content">`
```

//*вот собственно Кусочек кода для примера

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <h1>текст текст текст</h1>
</div>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td><?php functio("m[5]", "Tabl", "pole"); ?></td>// Это функция
   </tr>
</table>
</div>';
<?php require_once '../shablone.php'; ?>
```

Переменную нужно объявить в шаблоне (это и происходит). HTML часть нормально встает, а PHP фигово. Подскажите, как засунуть php и HTML код  в одну переменную или чтоб php код не куда не девался?

Comment: @Dmitriy_1, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: что именно значит "фигово встаёт пхп" ? какое расширение у файла в котором находится код?

Comment: @Dmitriy_1, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д. @Dmitriy_1, Пожалуйста, оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, что php код будет в html файле. Чтобы потом сервер мог обрабатывать этот код надо добавить в .htaccess строчку:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

Только всё равно это не поможет. Сервер эту страницу отдаст клиенту, а клиент её не выполнит, даже если у него свой сервер установлен.

Comment: Фигово встает php. то есть вообще не работает если в переменной находится, а если просто на странице написать php код то все хорошо работает. расширение php а подключенный шаблон естественно HTML

Comment: В переменной значит хранится строка. Чтобы код отработал надо чтобы строка была в двойных кавычках (""). Код в одинарных кавычках, апострофах, не сработает, а передастся как строка символов. Посмотри как отработает код:
{$x = 5;
echo "$x"; //выведет 5
echo '$x'; //выведет $x
}